# using remote copy (scp) to perform local copy

Tags: bash, performance, unix, scp, cp

I've got a script that copy some content from local to remote, where remote is given as an input argument.

To do so, I'm using `scp` and it also support local copy (meaning that the remote given as input matches the local).

I wonder if it worth the effort to change the script so that in this special case, `cp` will be called rather than `scp`. perhaps do you know if the internal implementation of `scp` do this for me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of worrying about which is faster, why not implement some branching inside the script

```
if [ "$1" = "local" ]
then
 #Use cp
else
 #Use scp
fi
```

That said, `scp` should be slower than `cp` for the manpage says :

> scp copies files between hosts on a network.  It uses ssh(1) for 
>   data transfer, and uses the same authentication and provides the
>   same security as ssh(1).  Unlike rcp(1), scp will ask for passwords
>   or passphrases if they are needed for authentication.

The overhead in `scp` is the time taken in authenticating the host and guest before a transfer occurs.

But you can use the `-o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost` option with `scp` as a workaround.

```
scp -o NoHostAuthenticationForLocalhost target destination
```

should be as fast as `cp`

Comment: The overhead of `scp` authenticating the local host would only happen if the filename were specified in `host:path` format such as `localhost:/path/to/file`.  With a simple path that doesn't have a host such as just `/path/to/file`, `scp` just copies the file directly to/from the filesystem.  Which makes sense given how `scp` works - it copies directly to/from the file system when it's used to copy to/from another host.

Comment: @AndrewHenle : Hmm, the manpage says, `Local file names can be made
     explicit using absolute or relative pathnames to avoid scp treating file
     names containing ‘:’ as host specifiers.`  But,imho,this doesn't change the default behavior of `scp`. Could you paste the part from the manpage to support your point.  Or probably i need to look into the implementation..

Comment: That's to force `scp` to treat a file with a `':'` character in its name as a local file. `/this/is/a/local/file` is *always* treated as a local file. When `scp` copies a file from a remote host to the local file system, it doesn't authenticate the local host. Likewise, when it copies from the local system to a remote system, again, it doesn't authenticate the local host. Why would `scp` then authenticate the local host when it's simply doing a copy from a local file system to a local file system? Examine the output from something like `strace -o /tmp/strace.out scp /tmp/infile /tmp/outfile`.